# how to make clicking on the item in "share" form with android espresso test

Tags: android, share, android-espresso

Trying to test the share function of the app, which is in the app it calls createChooser() to open the "sharing" chooser form.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share something"));
```

Question is after the "sharing" chooser form is up how to simulate the clicking on some listed apps item, lets say there is app has description "AppName". Tried following it does not work, the chooser form stays there until the test timeout.

tried:

```
onView(withContentDescription("AppName"))
            .perform(click());
```

and:

```
onView(withText("AppName"))
            .perform(click());
```

Comment: what is package of the app in which you want to share something?

Answer (score -1):

Below is the example to share something in whatsapp:

```
Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
waIntent.setType("text/plain");
waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");//package name of whatsapp
waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share Something");//text to share
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent,"Share via..."));
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks Scion. But My question is not how to open the sharing chooser. After the chooser is up, I want to simulate the clicking on a app with in espresso test. Or I missed something in you answer?

Comment: i dont think thats possible in my knowledge